# Error while installing sklearn library in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I simply run this command: `!pip install sklearn`
It gives me error:

```
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post10.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried to uninstall it and then again install but it went all in the vain.

I want to import : `from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB, GaussianNB, MultinomialNB` for my work anything is working

Answer (score 0):

You should install scikit-learn:

```
!pip install scikit-learn
```